# Fire JavaScript event on object creation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Is there any way to fire an event when an object of a certain type is created?

I have an `<div>` element with `editableContent="true"` and when the user presses enter within the `<div>`, a new `<div>` is created that takes up just that line. Is it possible to have an event fire whenever a `<div>` object is created within my original `<div>` object?

I know one way to do this would to listen for keystrokes and on an 'enter' key being pressed, do a bunch of logic to figure out what to do, but this seems a lot less elegant - so it would be great if there was another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the a bunch of [DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMActivate) and some of them will be [supported by firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events) for example. But I dont think that IE will support only one of them. [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) is  a complete list. 
First you can fire a custom event every time you create a new div, or you have a settimeout that checks every second if the count of you divs childnodes has changed.

Comment: the DOMNodeInserted event should be what I need. luckily it's supported by everyone but IE.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that creates a div when you press enter.  Why don't you just add a function call at the end of it.

```
function createDiv(){
  //create div 
  //append div
  divCreated();
}
```

Comment: I don't have a function that creates a div when you press enter, the div is created automatically (this is just the standard behavior of an object with contentEditable=true; )

Answer (score 1):

There's no default callbacks for new elements creating. The first thing I have in mind - you can add an event listener for mouseUp event and check content delta (changed part) - if it looks like an element markup with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody who looking for a way to react to changes in a DOM should take into consideration [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It is a standard DOM4 feature currently implemented in **all latest** (even not *all modern* but latest!) browsers.