# Event For DOM Object Creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would one fire an event that fires every time a div is created?

I was thinking something along the lines of this, but clearly not.

```
$("#content").on("create", "div.block", function () {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});
});
```

I have discovered MutationObserver (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/165737), however as seen in the comments this does not work in IE.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate. Try reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321060/fire-javascript-event-on-object-creation

Comment: I think you'll find there are other browsers (besides IE) where the DOM4 mutation observers don't work either.

Comment: Try to take a look at this: https://github.com/snesin/jcade

Comment: As an alternative of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), you may use a timmer and check the length of the `$('content div.block').length` with initial length.

Comment: What do you need that event for? Looks like a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You want to know when a `div` is *created* or when it's appended to the document?

Comment: @Bergi I want to be able to add some functionality to all divs when they are inserted into the DOM based on data that is set against the div.

Comment: @nnnnnn what other browser limitations are there? I have only seen references saying IE so far. (apprently it is supported in IE10)

Comment: @DavidThomas I have a menu that loads pages into a div on the right hand side of the screen. This page that is loaded contains these div.block objects. I would like to fire the event on the creation of these.

Comment: @M.S, Check my answer (also fiddles and comment link), you may want something like this but not sure.

Comment: When last I looked, which was a while ago, it was just Chrome and FF, but I guess the other well known browsers have caught up. Though I think it is IE11, not 10. Anyway, I was thinking of mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a mutation event (DOMNodeInserted)... however IE might not fully capable of dealing with that.

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/AAd8f/

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('body').append('<div style="width:30px;height:30px;border:1px solid black"></div>');
    });


    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {

        $(e.target).addClass('blue');
    });
});
```

I like to note that it is better to use callback events instead of listening to the DOM. You'll need to write a callback after a div is inserted in the DOM. I don't think there is an other (non-hacky) way to accomplish this.

Comment: This is pretty much similar to what I was hoping for, unfortunatly even the fiddle does not seem to work in IE10 as was suggested in your answer. (Other browsers I have tested seem fine)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this instead of [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to get notified when ever a `div.block` has been added to the `div#content`

```
$(function(){
    var c = $('#content'), l = c.find('.block').length;
    setInterval(function(){
        var lOld = l;
        if(c.find('.block').length > lOld) {
            l = c.find('.block').length;
            c.find('.block').css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/4eTcx/3/) and here is [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/4eTcx/5/) with multiple `Background color` effect.

Comment: Another [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4eTcx/7/) to get the new element after insertion so `OP` can check the last element's `text/html` or whatever he wants.

Comment: This works great, however it does seem like quite an overhead running a timer all the time. Would that be the case?

Comment: @M.S, it's expensive though but won't be a problem (performance) I think, at least it works on every browsers with ease, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394010/two-javascript-timers-vs-one-timer-for-performance-is-it-worth-dropping-one).